# Grep based on the first unique value

Tags: awk

I have a huge file like this:

```
computer1 ram1.2 500
computer1 ram1.3 500
computer1 ram1.2 100
computer1 ram1.3 250
computer1 hdd0.1 205
computer2 ram1.2 400
computer2 ram1.3 2.3
computer2 ram6   12
computer2 hdd0.1 240
computer2 hdd0.1 223
computer2 ram6   120
```

I need to grep only the first value from the second column like this:

```
computer1 ram1.2 500
computer1 ram1.3 500
computer1 hdd0.1 205
computer2 ram1.2 400
computer2 ram1.3 2.3
computer2 ram6   12
computer2 hdd0.1 240
```

I tried with awk `! a[$2]++` but it's not working for me.

Comment: `awk '!a[$1$2]++' file`?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/OVx8t1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the following

```
 awk '!seen[$1$2]++' file.ext
```

and from this

```
$ cat file.ext
computer1 ram1.2 500
computer1 ram1.3 500
computer1 ram1.2 100
computer1 ram1.3 250
computer1 hdd0.1 205
computer2 ram1.2 400
computer2 ram1.3 2.3
computer2 ram6   12
computer2 hdd0.1 240
computer2 hdd0.1 223
computer2 ram6   120
```

you obtain this

```
$ awk '!seen[$1$2]++' file.ext
computer1 ram1.2 500
computer1 ram1.3 500
computer1 hdd0.1 205
computer2 ram1.2 400
computer2 ram1.3 2.3
computer2 ram6   12
computer2 hdd0.1 240
```

Comment: The $X instruction indicates the column to take in consideration. Where X indicates the index of the column starting from 1 to n. X=0 is equivalent to the full line

Comment: If the values of columns like this (not common)
`computer1 ram21.2 500
computer1 ram41.3 500
computer1 ram51.2 100
computer1 ram14.3 250
computer1 hd0.1 205
computer2 ram21.2 400
computer2 ram71.3 2.3
computer2 ram65   12
computer2 hd60.1 240
computer2 hd80.1 223
computer2 ram86   120`
what will the command

Comment: which is the request and the expected output?

Comment: simply like input
`computer1 ram21.2 500
computer1 ram21.22 500
computer1 ram21.2 700
computer1 ram41.3 500 
computer1 ram41.13 500 
computer2 ram21.2 400
computer2 ram21.2 800
computer2 ram71.3 2.3 
computer2 ram715.3 2.3`
and output will be like 
`computer1 ram21.2 500
computer1 ram41.3 500 
computer2 ram21.2 400
computer2 ram71.3 2.3`

Comment: You can use the same command... i don't see the difference with the question